# Dynamically change font size on a UISegmentControl

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I'm trying to change the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property on a UISegmentControl.

This is what I have so far (that isn't working):

```
for (id segment in [self.regionTypeSC subviews])
{
    for (id label in [segment subviews])
    {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *labelOfSegment = (UILabel *)label;
            labelOfSegment.numberOfLines = 1;
            labelOfSegment.minimumScaleFactor = 4.0/[UIFont labelFontSize];
            labelOfSegment.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

        }
    }           
}
```

Any suggestions on this logic (logically, whats wrong with it?) - or go down a separate path?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of messing around I found out that you need to call layoutifneeded before destroying the label.

So working code looks like:

```
for (id segment in [self.regionTypeSC subviews])
{
    for (id label in [segment subviews])
    {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *labelOfSegment = (UILabel *)label;

            labelOfSegment.numberOfLines = 1;
            labelOfSegment.minimumScaleFactor = 4.0/[UIFont labelFontSize];
            labelOfSegment.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

            [self.regionTypeSC layoutIfNeeded];
        }
    }           
}
```

:)